# How do I Get SharePoint 2010 WebApplication-scoped features to Activate Only on One Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I am developing a solution for SharePoint 2010 SP1. My solution provides several timer jobs, which are instantiated using a feature and a feature receiver.

The feature is scoped to a WebApplication, which seemed natural since the timer jobs are associated with the same web application. The solution is also a full-trust solution.

The solution deploys to a specific web application (http://portal.xyz.net), and only to that web application; however, it appears that the feature gets activated on *all* web applications within the farm, except Central Administration. As a result, the timer job gets created on all web applications.

This causes failures in some cases, and redundant code execution in others. What I really want is for the feature to activate *only* on the web application to which I deploy the solution.

Any ideas on how I can configure this properly?

### Update 1

We have tried deploying the solution three ways, all with the same behavior:

- Using Visual Studio
- Using the Central Administration web application
- Using the following PowerShell command:

  Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\Nu.SharePoint.Portal.wsp
  Install-SPSolution -Identity Nu.SharePoint.Portal.wsp -GACDeployment -WebApplication http://portal

After the deploy step in any case, we see the solution deployed to the single web application, but the WebApplication-scoped features are activated on all web applications except central admin. The behavior we want is to activate these features *only* on the application that we deploy to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent the timer job from activating on all of the web applications you just need to set the Feature property called "Activate On Default" to False. When you deploy the feature to a web application the feature will not activate so you just need to activate it through Central Admin or a PowerShell script.
You can modify the Feature property in Visual Studio by opening the Feature Designer, selecting the feature on the left and it's the first property in the Property window.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Feature and Give F4
2. In the Properties window, Select False in Activate on Default Property.
3. Then deploy the solution.

Comment: Thank you @Dinesh. While this solution prevents the feature from being automatically activated on *any* application, I am looking for a solution to activate the feature automatically *only* on web applications to which the solution is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

did you use PowerShell to deploy you WSP or are you deploying from within Visual Studio. By using the PowerShell commandlets for SharePoint you could easily configure where the features will be deployed to.

```
Add-PSSnapIn Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\install\MyWSP.wsp
Deploy-SPSolution -Identity MyWSP.wsp -GACDeployment -WebApplication http://mysite
```

While Deploying WSPs manually from CA you're also able to select the WebApplication your features will be deployed to.

By default your features are deployed to all WebApps in your Farm

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added to my question some details in response. I am looking, however, for a way to not follow this default behavior. Also, note that the third cmdlet should be called `Install-SPSolution`.